# Are there any foods that have been suggested in Islam for a good sex life?

Tags: quran, hadith, practical-islam, food

Are there any foods that have been suggested in Islam for a good sex life? If yes, could someone please reference to some Hadith or Quran regarding this?

Comment: As far as I know there is nothing like that in Islam. I think you must ask first   "Are there any foods that have been suggested in Islam for a good sex life?".

Answer (score 1):

**Summary**: Surveying online fatawa revealed that while many foods are listed by some scholars as suggestions, no foods are singled out in Islam as good choices for aphrodisiacs.  The closest I found was [aloeswood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agarwood), which was mentioned in ahadith as a cure for disease, which [ibn Hajar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Asqalani) also says "stirs desire".  One can use medicines like [Viagra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sildenafil), if medically appropriate.

---

[Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/79072) writes about [aphrodisiacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aphrodisiac):

> For example, [al-Haafiz Ibn Hajar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ibn_Hajar_al-Asqalani) (may Allaah have mercy on him) said, when discussing the words of the Prophet (peace and blessings of Allaah be upon him), **“You should use this [aloes-wood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agarwood) (al-‘ood al-hindi) for in it there are seven cures”** (narrated by Muslim (5260) and Muslim (4103)): Aloes-wood (al-‘ood al-hindi) is the well-known Indian costmary, and among its benefits are that it aids digestion, **stirs desire** and clears up pimples. End quote from Fath al-Baari.

These are the relevant ahadith on sunnah.com: [Sahih Muslim 287](https://sunnah.com/muslim/39/116-117); [Sahih al-Bukhari 5718](https://sunnah.com/urn/53640); Sunan Ibn Majah [1](https://sunnah.com/urn/1275070), [2](https://sunnah.com/urn/1275130) (both sahih); [Sunan Abi Dawud 3877](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/29/23).

> The same is also said of [fenugreek](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenugreek), [pistachios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pistachio), [carob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceratonia_siliqua), melon-seeds and so on. See al-Adaab al-Shar’iyyah by Ibn Muflih, 7/3 and 2/370, 375.

They continue about medicines:

> Drugs and medicines that are used for this purpose. The basic principle concerning these is that they are also permissible ...

Abdul Adheem al-Muhtadi al-Bahrani (from [ImamReza.net](https://www.imamreza.net/eng/imamreza.php?id=7577)) writes:

> The following foods have great effects in strengthening the nerves: honey with ginger, pepper, saffron, the cooked head of a cow or sheep, beets cooked in milk, mulberries, bananas, eggs with onion, mutton, carrots, pears, grapes, liver, sweet pomegranates, and endives.

---

Other fatawa on aphrodisiacs: [Another Islam Q&A fatwa](https://islamqa.info/en/159675); [IslamWeb](https://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=5385); [Abuaaliyah.com](http://www.abuaaliyah.com/2016/09/26/aphrodisiacs-in-islam/).

Fatawa on treating impotence: [Islam Q&A](https://islamqa.info/en/6268); [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=22550); [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2017/03/22/husband-impotent-what-to-do/).  There were others I found which just say "go see a doctor".

[AboutIslam](http://Ruqyah) discusses the possibility of sihr (witchcraft) playing a role in impotence, and suggests [ruqya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exorcism_in_Islam) (exorcism) as a cure.  [AskImam](http://www.askimam.org/public/question_detail/17805) discusses sex therapy.  [SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2017/03/22/husband-impotent-what-to-do/) discusses using the [prayer of need](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2009/07/24/how-does-one-perform-the-prayer-of-need-salat-al-haja/).